# matlab: inputdlg dialog box comes with tick labels

Tags: matlab, input, dialog, axis-labels

I have a user input request box basically written as matlab suggests in http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputdlg.html .

```
prompt = {'Enter spot number'};
dlg_title = 'Input';
num_lines = 1;
def = {'9'};
answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);
handles.count = str2double(answer{1});
```

However, the dialog box comes with axis labels as the image shows in the link below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1OyP.jpg

Edit:
It turns out that the windowsbuttonmotion function is doing the thing. I evaluated it within the function, not by calling a second function. Like this:

```
function figure1_WindowButtonMotionFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

global loop_counter diameter

pos = get(gca, 'currentpoint'); % get mouse location on figure
x = pos(1,1); y = pos(1,2); % assign locations to x and y
set(handles.lbl_x, 'string', ['x loc:' num2str(x)]); % update text for x loc
set(handles.lbl_y, 'string', ['y loc:' num2str(y)]); % update text for y loc 
const = diameter/2;

for i = 1:loop_counter
    center(i,:) = getPosition(handles.trap(handles.unselected(i)))+const;
    if(((x-center(i,1))^2+(y-center(i,2))^2)<= const^2)
        setColor(handles.trap(handles.unselected(i)), 'red');
    else
        setColor(handles.trap(handles.unselected(i)), 'blue');
    end
end

guidata(hObject, handles)
```

How can I get rid of them?

Thanks.

Comment: Which Matlab version do you use? It is not happening for me. Do you run this out of a GUI? Do have other figures open?

Comment: I use Matlab 2013b. This is the first time this happens for me, too. There is a main GUI that has a button which opens inputdlg when it is pressed on.

Comment: Does it also happen when you run the code from command window without any GUI? Sounds strange, but have you restarted Matlab?

Comment: No, it does not happen. As you suggested, I restarted Matlab.And it is still there.

Comment: Can you share some code of the GUI? If it not happens from command window than it must be related to the code from the GUI. However, we cannot not help you in this case without any code.

Comment: I have just edited my post.

Comment: Thanks. Running this piece of code works fine for me (i.e., the input dialog looks correct).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Than the usual suspect might be the handles to main gui figure. I am looking into it.

Comment: Re-edited. Now I know the what causes this, but I still don't know how.

Comment: Just an idea. Maybe the `gca` call generates axis in the figure of the dialog. Thus, the callback is executed while the input dialog and not the GUI is `gcf`. Therefore, an axis is created by `gca` (since non exists so far in the GUI figure).

Comment: That's right. I think I need to take the axis position another way. Or leave just the way it is.  Thanks.